# Azure website taking a long time for page load

Tags: azure

I have an Azure-website(not a cloud service) that takes around 20 seconds to load if it is idle for long-time(3 hours, for example). One solution to this is to write a script that pings the website every 20 minutes or so. However, this will cost me and I want to avoid this. Can someone please tell me how I can overcome this long page-load problem, in a simpler manner, like a configuration settings change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no free lunch! If you want fast load, you have to keep your site up and warm. So the solution you found - ping it every 20 minutes is good one. Btw, keeping it live by pinging every 20 minutes will not increase your bill that much.

Comment: strange... even after paying for the hosting charges, it is still considered free lunch

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to answer but when looking around on this topic I found this post:

http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/job-scheduling-in-windows-azure/

Absolute lifesaver!